# Find all values of parameter $a$, that $ x^3-ax^2+3x-2=0$ has no solutions when $0<x<2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, parametric, cubics

Find all values of parameter $a$, that $f(x) = x^3-ax^2+3x-2=0$ has no solutions when $0<x<2$. I tried to find all zeros of derivative to find max and min value of $f(x)$ to check is $\min<0<\max$ and then substitute them in the equation, but then I failed. What should I do, or what theorem I should use?

Comment: Do you know the cubic formula?

Comment: Which formula? For getting roots of cubic equation? It should be much easier, I am sure

Comment: Find $x_{\min}$ and $x_{\max}$ using $a$ and then find all the $a$'s that will cause $0\notin[x_{\min},x_{\max}]$

Comment: It's hard, I tried, I didn't end it in 1,5 hour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x)={x^3+3x-2\over x^2}$$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$, so the line $y=a$ doesn't cuts the graph of $f$ for $x\in(0,2)$ if $a>f(2) = 3$.

Comment: thanks, I got it